# POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/sign_in 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Имеется Ember приложение, которое работает в паре с Rails. Актуальные версии.

Маршрут прописан следующий:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  devise_for :users, only: %i[sessions]
end
```

Контроллер:

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    render json: params
  end
end
```

Возвращает:

```
{"user":{"password":"111111","email":"email@gmail.com"},"format":"json","controller":"api/sessions","action":"create","session":{"user":{"password":"111111","email":"email@gmail.com"}}}
```

Вроде все нормально. Когда нажимаю на кнопку "Войти" в Ember приложении, то Rails в ответ шлет json, представленный выше.

Но если в код выше добавить `super`, то получаю ошибку:

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super do |user|
      if request.format.json?
        render json: user && return
      end
    end
  end
end
```

> {"error":"translation missing: ru.devise.failure.api_user.unauthenticated"}

Любое упоминание `super` в методе `create` вызывает эту ошибку. И я не понимаю в чем дело.

Я всего лишь хочу авторизовать пользователя в Rails и отдать токен Ember приложению.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А что у вас в логах SessionsController? Пользователь точно существует с такими почтой и паролем? В контроллере вам не нужно переписывать экшн, потому как вы ничего к нему не добавляете, достаточно добавить строку `respond_to :json` в сам класс Api::SessionsController

Comment: @Василиса Пользователь конечно существует, иначе бы была ошибка, мол, что его нет. В контроллере мне нужно переписать экшен, так как нужно отдать токен во фронт. В логах SessionsController нет никаких ошибок. Просто как только в экшене появляется `super`, то ловлю 401. Все остальное отдается во фронт - например `render json:  params` сработает нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим путем:

`devise_for` поместил в корень, переопределив `sessions`:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: 'users/sessions'
}
```

Контроллер стал таким - `Users::SessionsController`. Экшен таким:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def create
  super do |user|
    data = {
      token: user.authentication_token,
      email: user.email
    }
    return render json: data, status: :created
  end
end
```

По итогу данные из фронта уходят. Сервер в ответ дает email и токен.

Данный вариант не так красив, так как приходится иметь два endpoint'a - для devise и для всего остального.

Почему `devise_for` не хочет работать из оберток в виде `namespace` я так и не понял.